# DynamoDB: check if item has value before update

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

My items look like this:

```
{id: some_id,
 owners: ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

Say `owner = "2"`. I want to write a pre-condition which ensures that `owner` was in `owners` before the item update (`put`). I have already written a precondition to ensure the item id exists before update:

```
var params = {
        TableName: tableNames[event.pathParameters.resourceType],
        Item: item,
        ConditionExpression: "attribute_exists(id)"
    };
```

And I want to do the same for `get` and `scan`/`query` . Is this possible or I should instead get the item first then verify the condition in code before updating the item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `contains` to check whether the owners has the expected owner id.

```
"ConditionExpression": "contains (owners, :ownersStr)",
"ExpressionAttributeValues": { 
    ":ownersStr" : "2"
}
```